# CSS make div both change color and move on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

I made a box on my screen and I want it to change color and move to the bottom right corner when hovered over.
So far I have this... which only changes color. I can't figure out how to make the div slowly both change color and move to the bottom-right

```
.topper {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px
}

.topper:hover {
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transform: translate(1400px, 800px);
  -webkit-transition: all 20s ease-in-out;
}


<div class="topper">
</div>
```

SOrt of works but is there any way to make it automatically og to the right-bottom instead of me writting specific locations like 1400px/800px? I want to use ONLY css

Comment: If you want the div to move...how are you are you moving it. Problem is, once you start moving it...the hover will start to fail Javascript is a better option here.

Comment: I want to do it all CSS. I'll have my mouse over it the whole time. It will only move and change color while my mouse follows it

Comment: The mouse doesn't follow automatically you''d have to move it...either way...what are you doing to change the position of the div?

Comment: I changed it a little. I use -webkit-transform: translate(1400px, 800px);
  -webkit-transition: all 20s ease-in-out;
} now and it sort of works but those positions... 1400px and 800px are random. Is there any automatic way for it to just to right to the right-bottom?

Comment: You need a context...the bottom right of *what*? Try looking into positioning...not transforms.

Comment: Ugh bottom-right of the screen... page kinda

Comment: Again, look into positioning. Try stuff then come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added the move from `left:0` to `left:100%` and from `top:0` to `top:100%` and have used the css `calc()` method to reduce the object size from the final length (100%).

```css
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
margin: 0px;
}

.topper {
  left:0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.topper:hover {  
  left: calc(100% - 100px);
  top: calc(100% - 100px);
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: all 8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 8s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="topper">
</div>
```

Comment: Great except my box must go from top-left to bottom-right

Comment: Why you added transition to the simple .topper too? And what does left: calc(100% - 100px);
  top: calc(100% - 100px); this do? I tried adding these to my original code and they don't work.

Comment: You must use your object size instead of 100px. 100px is the size of the element on this example. The animation are in the .topper to animate the journey back to its original place (when the cursor leaves the element).